# Can I assign a subdomain to an IP-Address?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, ip, virtualhost, subdomain

I am currently in the Process of moving from one server to another. And I am currently setting up my apache2. However on the old server I used several subdomains. Now i wanted to test these subdomains on the new server, however it seems hat subdomain.xx.xx.xx.xx (subdomain.ip-address) does not seem to work. Is this impossible or is it just me getting the config wrong?

**my config**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/tld.com
<Directory>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/tld.com>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
            # in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
            #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
</Directory>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
ServerSignature On

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
    ServerName subdomain.62.75.145.146
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure that your subdomain is pointing to the correct IP.
2. Ensure that the subdomain is listed as a host in your virtualhost config, either ServerName or Server Alias.

If either of these don't solve the problem, you're going to need to give us more info - post your apache vhost config at the very least.

--Edit--
Okay, first off, `subdomain.62.75.145.146` is not a valid DNS name. You cannot just add on arbitrary hostnames to your server's IP address. You need to *either* have a dedicated IP for this virtualhost *or* assign a valid DNS name. If you're just doing testing, you can just add an entry to the hosts file on your client mapping `subdomain.example.com` to `62.75.145.146`. That line would look like this:

```
62.75.145.146    subdomain.example.com
```

Then set `subdomain.example.com` as the ServerName in your VirtualHost. At that point, you should be able to visit `subdomain.example.com` in your browser and it will serve from the correct vhost.

If the hosts file is not a good solution for you, you'll need to create a proper DNS `A` or `CNAME` record for the subdomain. The process for doing that it outside the scope of this question, but there should be plenty of info in other ServerFault articles about that process.

Comment: Added my config